# Val_acc oscillates and doesn't converge when training with TPU compared with GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tpu

I have implemented a MobileNets deep learning architecture and trained it on  Cifar-100. For that I use google Colab, and it worked correctly with their GPU, although I didn't get a very good accuracy. But when I train on their TPU, for the first 10 epochs the validation accuracy essentially stays at 0, and then when it goes up it is inconsistent and not steadily increasing as with the GPU.

You can see what I mean on these two screens : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFC96.jpg

I am a bit stuck, as I don't fully understand how TPU works, I know it has to divide the work, but other than that... I guess I could try to modify the learning rate of the optimizer manually ? For it to learn more quickly. But that does not explain why the accuracy drops at the end.

```py
"""Cifar-100
"""

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!pip install tensorflow==1.13.2

import os
os.listdir()
os.chdir("./drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Cifar-100")

#IMPORTS FOR MODELS
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, DepthwiseConv2D, Flatten, Activation, Dropout, BatchNormalization, AveragePooling2D, Convolution2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import pdb

#DEFINITION OF MODELS

def depthwise_conv_1x1_conv(strides, n_filters, x):
    x = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size=3, strides=strides, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation='relu')(x)
    x = Convolution2D(filters=n_filters, kernel_size=1, strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation='relu')(x)
    return x

def make_mobile_net(args, input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = Input(shape = input_shape, batch_size = args.batch_size)
    x = inputs
    x = Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3 , strides=1, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation='relu')(x)

    for i in [(1, 64), (1, 128), (1, 128), (1, 256), (1, 256), (2, 512), (1, 512),(1, 512),(1, 512),(1, 512),(1, 512), (2, 1024), (1, 1024)] :
        x = depthwise_conv_1x1_conv(i[0], i[1], x)

    x = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=8, strides=1)(x)

    x = Flatten()(x)
    if args.add_dense :
        x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)

    y = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs = [y])
    return model


builders = {'MobileNet': make_mobile_net }

def build_network(args, input_shape, num_classes):
    return builders[args.model](args, input_shape, num_classes)

#IMPORTS FOR TRAINING

import sys

from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar100
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import argparse
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint

#TRAINING ARGUMENTS


class Arguments(object):
    def __init__(self, logdir= "./logs/", data_augment = False , normalize = False , add_dense = False , sgd = False , model = "MobileNet", batch_size = 128 ):
        self.logdir = logdir # The directory in which to store the logs (default: ./logs/)
        self.data_augment = data_augment # Whether to use data augmentation
        self.add_dense = add_dense # Should we add an additional dense layer before softmax
        self.sgd = sgd # Should we use sgd instead of adam for optimization
        self.model = model
        self.batch_size = batch_size


args = Arguments()

#Loading Cifar-100 Dataset, 60.000 32x32 color images
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data(label_mode='fine') #or label_mode = 'coarse'

num_classes = 100
img_rows = x_train.shape[1]
img_cols = x_train.shape[2]
num_channels = 3
num_train = x_train.shape[0]
num_test = x_test.shape[0]
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, num_channels)

def split(X, y, test_size):
    idx = np.arange(X.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    nb_test = int(test_size * X.shape[0])
    return X[nb_test:,:, :], y[nb_test:],\
           X[:nb_test, :, :], y[:nb_test]

x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.1)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, num_channels)
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)

x_val = x_val.reshape(x_val.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, num_channels)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val, num_classes)

x_test = x_test.reshape(num_test, img_rows, img_cols, num_channels)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = build_network(args, input_shape, num_classes)
model.summary()

# Callbacks

def generate_unique_logpath(logdir, raw_run_name):
    i = 0
    while(True):
        run_name = raw_run_name + "-" + str(i)
        log_path = os.path.join(logdir, run_name)
        if not os.path.isdir(log_path):
            return log_path
        i = i + 1

logpath = generate_unique_logpath(args.logdir, args.model)
tbcb = TensorBoard(log_dir=logpath)
print("=" * 20)
print("The logs will be saved in {}".format(logpath))
print("=" * 20)

checkpoint_filepath = os.path.join(logpath,  "best_model.h5")
checkpoint_cb = ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_filepath, save_best_only=True)

# Compilation
if args.sgd :
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='sgd',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
else :
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))

# Training
if args.data_augment:
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.3,
                  zoom_range=0.1,
                  rotation_range=10.)

    train_flow = datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=args.batch_size*8)
    history = model.fit_generator(train_flow,
            steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]/128,
            epochs=50,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
            callbacks=[tbcb, checkpoint_cb])

else:
    history = tpu_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
            batch_size=args.batch_size*8,
            epochs=40,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data = (x_val, y_val),
            callbacks=[tbcb, checkpoint_cb])


# Evaluation of the best model
model = load_model(checkpoint_filepath)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1, batch_size = args.batch_size*8)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

args.batch_size=None
inference_model = build_network(args, input_shape, num_classes)
checkpoint_filepath = './logs/MobileNet-3/best_model.h5'
inference_model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)

if args.sgd :
    inference_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='sgd',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
else :
    inference_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
score = inference_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

# %load_ext tensorboard.notebook
# %tensorboard --logdir logs

checkpoint_filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've retrained the model but with more epochs (70), and it seems to attain the same accuracy as with the GPU at the end.

There is still a little drop in the middle, I guess it is somewhat intrinsic to the way the TPU trains the model :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOoCx.jpg